# Get month name with different month start and end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Getting the month for the current date is, obviously, straight forward, but I'm needing to get the month name with a different end date.

I need to get the month name with the start date of the month being the first Thursday after the first Wednesday of the month and the end date of the month being the first Wednesday of the following month.  It's for an accounting thing, so I'm not going to argue with the spec!

e.g. for 2014, January would run from 9th Jan - 5th Feb, February would run from 6th February - 5th March, March would run from 6th March - 2nd April.

Comment: So, if a month starts on a Thursday, the previous month overlaps this one by a week (because the first Wednesday is the 7th of that month, but the first Thursday is the 1st)? I doubt that is the case, so I suspect the spec needs tweaking (or, if it doesn't, what is the correct answer during those periods?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In that case it would start on the 2nd Thurdsay - will update the initial question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a table with your 'accounting months' in it, having a start date, end date and month name columns.

You could then query this to find the row where your date is between the start and end dates and return the month name.  Putting this into a scalar function would then allow it to be reusable and relatively easily updated for next years months as well.

Comment: While I agree that this would be the simplest, it's not necessarily the most sustainable!

Comment: @franglais - with just 1000 rows, you can model over 80 years. It shouldn't take very long to populate such a table. Doing it as an expression/function is probably going to be quite painful (not that I'm not trying to fathom one out :-))

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Fair enough - best way of populating the table without doing it manually?

Comment: @franglais - you might need to tell us what the rules are governing your start and end months.

Comment: Sorry, just had another look at the question and can see that you have  that there already...

Answer (score 2):

I think, as per Paddy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450762/15498), a lookup table is the simplest thing to do. Here's one way to generate the rows for it:

```
; With Numbers(n) as (
    select 4 union all select 5
), Months as (
    select CONVERT(date,'20010104') as StartDt,CONVERT(date,'20010207') as EndDt,
           DATENAME(month,'20010103') as Month
    union all
    select DATEADD(week,n1.n,StartDt),DATEADD(week,n2.n,EndDt),
           DATENAME(month,DATEADD(week,n1.n,StartDt))
    from Months,Numbers n1,Numbers n2 --Old-skool join, just for once
    where DATEPART(day,DATEADD(week,n1.n,StartDt)) between 2 and 8 and
          DATEPART(day,DATEADD(week,n2.n,EndDt)) between 1 and 7 and
          StartDt < '21000101'
)
select * from Months option (maxrecursion 0)
```

(CW since this is effectively just an extension to Paddy's answer but I don't want to edit their answer, nor is it suitable for a comment

Comment: Ignore that comment, I'm being thick :D

Comment: Just a minor suggestion to that (brilliant) query.  The current query will bring back the end date as date 00:00:00 whereas it would be far better to bring it back as date 23:59:59!

Comment: @franglais - if you're thinking that, then you probably ought to be returning the day afterwards and using `<` for the comparison, rather than `<=` or `BETWEEN`. If time's involved, it's almost always cleaner to work with semi-open intervals where the start value is *inclusive* and the end value is *exclusive*. Because I'm sure you don't want to exclude e.g. a value with a timestamp at `23:59:59.537`.